# Blockchain-wallet-service Ubuntu 16.04 start --port 3000

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, bitcoin, blockchain

Im using Blockchain-wallet-service to programaticaly pay bitcoins from blockchain wallet.

I have globaly instal in node

```
$ npm install -g blockchain-wallet-service
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/blockchain-wallet-service

Now im using command:

```
$  sudo blockchain-wallet-service start --port 3000
```

It will start local service, but I can not find - how to run it forever, also after restart server like service...Some ideas?

Answer (score -1):

nohup blockchain-wallet-service start --port 3000 &